# How to convert negative decimal to hexadecimal?

Tags: javascript, hex, decimal

```
hex = Number(-59).toString(16)
```

hex is `-3b`

hex should be `ffffffffffffffC5`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: why hex should be c5? c5 is 197

Comment: sorry, ffffffffffffffC5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the number is negative, the sign is preserved. Especially if the radix is 2, it's returning the binary (zeros and ones) of the number preceeded by a - sign but the two's complement.

This is how the [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) method of the `Number` type works, it doesn't output the two's complement.

In other words, the `toString()` method converts the number as if it was positive displaying its hexadecimal representation, if that number is negative it just puts a minus `-` before it.

Comment: I see, I will write a function to get the conversation I need. Thanks!

Comment: @boom You are welcome, don't forget to accept his answer please if it answers your question. Thank you.